# How to find the i and j value of matrix element without using for loops?

Tags: python, matrix

Suppose I had a NumPy array

```
a = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
```

and like to find `i` and `j` value of `4` which is `i =row no = 2` and `j = column no = 0`

`i, j = 2, 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

4 has the row 1 and column 0 in your array

```
a = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]

for r, d in enumerate(a):
    if 4 in d:
        pos = (r, d.index(4))

print(pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [numpy.argwhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
>>> my_array = np.random.randint(0,10,20).reshape(5,4)
>>> print(my_array)
[[7 9 0 0]
 [8 3 2 1]
 [0 4 5 2]
 [7 3 1 6]
 [9 5 0 8]]
```

From the above array if you want to find all the indices where value is `2`, use

```
>>> print(np.argwhere(my_array == 2))
[[1 2]
 [2 3]]
```

if you only want the first index, use

```
>>> print(tuple(np.argwhere(my_array == 2)[0]))
(1, 2)
```

nb: please be aware that, if searched element is not present in your array, you will get an `IndexError` for second case